# Number of nonnegative integer solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3\le10$ with $x_1 \ge 1\ ,\ x_2\ge3$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Is there a general formula for this?

Comment: Yes, a small modification of Stars and Bars works. Do your natural numbers include $0$? Probably, else the problem would not say $x_1\ge 1$.

Comment: Yes $N$ includes $0$. I am guessing the answer is ${12-1-3 \choose 2 }$ but i have trouble with the intuition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am giving away up to $10$ identical candies among $3$ kids, with the provisos that Kid 1 gets at least $1,$ and Kid 2 gets at least $3$.

Give $1$ candy to Kid 1, and $3$ to Kid 2. Now we are distributing **up to** $6$ candies among $3$ kids. Invent a fourth kid, Kid 4, who will get all the "leftover" candies.

So the number of ways to carry out our task is the number of ways to distribute **all** $6$ candies among these $4$ kids. Standard Stars and Bars shows that there are $\binom{6+4-1}{4-1}$ ways to do this.

Comment: Oh, it seems like i have made a typo in the title. What I meant to write was $x_1+x_2+x_3=10$. Regardless your solution helped me understand the thinking behind it.

Comment: @ТеодорДяков: Might as well keep it that way, now you know how to deal with the twist $\le n$. For $=10$, Stars and Bars gives $\binom{6+3-1}{3-1}$.  I did not deal with the Stars and Bars intuition in my answer, since it seemed the main task was to explain how to deal with $\le$.

Comment: @ТеодорДяков: I am not quite happy with the "standard" Stars and Bars intuition. To me, distributing $n$ candies among $k$ kids so that **each** gets at least $1$ is clearly $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ (we choose $k-1$ places from $n-1$ to place separators). Then if $0$ is allowed, I think of it as distributing $n+k$ candies among $k$ kids, with each getting at least $1$ (which can be done in $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ ways) and then taking a candy away from each kid.

Comment: Yeah i knew about the Stars and Bars, the problem was $x_1\ge1\, x_2\ge 3$ but it seems like it can be reduced to $z+y+x_3\ge6\ ,  z=x_1-1\ , y=x_2-3$ and then use standard Stars and Bars.

Comment: @ТеодорДяков: The $\ge 1$, $\ge 3$ are no problem. You can either make a change of variable, as in your comment above, or explain it, as in the post, in terms of giving preliminary gifts of $1$ and $3$ to Kids 1 and 2. Depends on whether algebra or concrete view of the situation is more natural to you.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\,\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\,\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> 1. $\ds{\sum_{x_{1} = \color{#f00}{1}}^{\infty}
>    \sum_{x_{2} = \color{#f00}{3}}^{\infty}
>    \sum_{x_{3} = \color{#f00}{0}}^{\infty}
>    \delta_{x_{1}\ +\ x_{2}\ +\ x_{3}\,,\, s}\,\,\,}$ counts the number of triplets
>      $\ds{\pars{x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}}}$ with $\ds{x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} = s}$ because the *Kronecker Delta*
>      $\ds{\delta_{x_{1}\ +\ x_{2}\ +\ x_{3}\,,\, s}\,\,\,}$ is equal to $\ds{1}$ when the above condition is satisfied and $\ds{0}$ otherwise.
> 2. The next sum
>      $\ds{\sum_{s = 4}^{10}\cdots}$ completes the task by collecting the total sums
>      $\ds{s = 4,5,6,7,8,9,10}$.
> 3. The evaluation is straightforward with a *well known* Kronecker Delta integral representation which allows to sum over independent
>      $\ds{\braces{x_{i}, i = 1,2,3}}$.
> 4. Sums over $\ds{\braces{x_{i}, i,1,2,3}}$ can be extended to $\ds{\infty}$ because the Kronecker Delta doesn't allow the case
>      $\ds{x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} > s}$
>      $\ds{\pars{~it\ vanishes\ out\ in\ such\ cases~}}$.

\begin{align}
&\sum_{s = \color{#f00}{4}}^{\color{#f00}{10}}\sum_{x_{1} = \color{#f00}{1}}^{\infty}\sum_{x_{2} = \color{#f00}{3}}^{\infty}
\sum_{x_{3} = \color{#f00}{0}}^{\infty}\delta_{x_{1}\ +\ x_{2}\ +\ x_{3}\,,\, s}
\,\,\,=\,\,\,
\sum_{s = \color{#f00}{4}}^{\color{#f00}{10}}
\sum_{x_{1} = \color{#f00}{1}}^{\infty}\sum_{x_{2} = \color{#f00}{3}}^{\infty}
\sum_{x_{3} = \color{#f00}{0}}^{\infty}
\,\,\oint_{\verts{z} = \color{#f00}{1^{-}}}\,\,\,
{1 \over z^{s + 1 - x_{1} - x_{2} - x_{3}}}\,\,\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{s = \color{#f00}{4}}^{\color{#f00}{10}}\,\,
\oint_{\verts{z} = \color{#f00}{1^{-}}}\,\,{1 \over z^{s + 1}}
\pars{\sum_{x_{1} = \color{#f00}{1}}^{\infty}z^{x_{1}}}
\pars{\sum_{x_{2} = \color{#f00}{3}}^{\infty}z^{x_{2}}}
\pars{\sum_{x_{3} = \color{#f00}{0}}^{\infty}z^{x_{3}}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{s = \color{#f00}{4}}^{\color{#f00}{10}}\,\,
\oint_{\verts{z} = \color{#f00}{1^{-}}}\,\,{1 \over z^{s + 1}}
{z \over 1 - z}{z^{3} \over 1 - z}{1 \over 1 - z}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\sum_{s = \color{#f00}{4}}^{\color{#f00}{10}}\,\,
\oint_{\verts{z} = \color{#f00}{1^{-}}}\,\,
{1 \over z^{s - 3}\,\,\pars{1 - z}^{3}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{s = \color{#f00}{4}}^{\color{#f00}{10}}\,\,
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{-3 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}
\oint_{\verts{z} = \color{#f00}{1^{-}}}\,\,{1 \over z^{s - 3 - k}}
\,\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{s = \color{#f00}{4}}^{\color{#f00}{10}}\,\,
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{3 + k - 1\choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}\pars{-1}^{k}\,
\delta_{s - k - 3,1} 
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{s = \color{#f00}{4}}^{\color{#f00}{10}}\,\,
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\half\,\pars{k + 2}\pars{k + 1}
\delta_{k,s - 4}
\\[5mm] & =
\half\sum_{s = 0}^{6}\pars{s + 2}\pars{s + 1} = \color{#f00}{84}\quad
\pars{~\Longleftarrow\ \ul{final\ result}~}
\end{align}

> which is equivalent to
>   $$
> {2 \choose 2} + {3 \choose 2} + {4 \choose 2} + {5 \choose 2} + {6 \choose 2} +
> {7 \choose 2} + {8 \choose 2}
> $$