# Solve $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^6} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $$x^3 = \tan y\ \ \text{ so that }\ x^2 = \tan^{2/3}y$$

$$3x^2dx = \sec^2(y)dy$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^6}dx = \int_{1}^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{1+\tan^2y}\cdot \frac{\sec^2y}{3\tan^{2/3}y}dy = \frac{1}{3}\int_{1}^{\pi/4} \cot^{2/3}y\ dy$$

How should I proceed after this?

EDITED: Corrected the final integral and the limit from $45$ to $\pi/4$

Comment: Where's 45 from? Do you mean degrees? Then you should probably switch to radians.

Comment: Ah, yes! That will be $\pi/4$.

Comment: Yes that sounds reasonable, I'm on a diet anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take the long way using partial fractions, which gives you:
$$\underbrace{\frac{1}{3(x^2+1)}}_{f_1(x)}+\underbrace{\frac{\sqrt 3 x+2}{6(x^2+\sqrt3 x+1)}}_{f_2(x)}+\underbrace{\frac{3\sqrt3x-6}{18(-x^2+\sqrt3x-1)}}_{f_3(x)}$$
$$\int_0^1f_1(x)dx=\frac 13\int_0^1\frac 1{1+x^2}dx=\left[\arctan(x)\right]_0^1$$

$$\int_0^1f_2(x)dx=\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt 3 x+2}{6(x^2+\sqrt3 x+1)}dx=\frac 16\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt3x+1}{x^2+\sqrt3 x+1}+\frac{1}{x^2+\sqrt3 x+1}$$

From here on out it's pretty straightforward. The answer will involve logarithms and $\arctan$'s. It's similar for $f_3(x)$...

Comment: The final integral, where did you get the first term in that expression?

Comment: @piepi sorry, I put the $\sqrt 3$ in the wrong place, all fixed now!

Comment: Dear lord, did I get scared!

Comment: @piepi Hahaha! I was surprised when I read it again!

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\,\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\,\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
The *exponent* $\ds{2 \over 3}$ in the $\ds{\cot}$*-function* makes it rather cumbersome. You can go to other straightforward avenues.

> $\ds{\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over x^{6} + 1}}:\ ?}$.

1.\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over x^{6} + 1}} & =
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{6} \over 1 - x^{12}}\,\dd x =
{1 \over 12}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{-11/12}\,\,\, -\,\,\, x^{-5/12} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x \\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 12}\pars{\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{-5/12} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{-11/12} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 12}\bracks{\Psi\pars{7 \over 12} - \Psi\pars{1 \over 12}}
\qquad\pars{~\Psi:\ Digamma\ Function~}
\end{align}
With $\ds{\pars{~p = 1,2,3\ldots\,,\ q = 2,3,4\ldots\,,\ p < q~}}$,
$\ds{\Psi\pars{p \over q}}$ is evaluated with (  see G & R,
$\ds{\mathbf{8.363}}$.6 ) the identity:
$$
\Psi\pars{p \over q} =
-\gamma -\ln\pars{2q} - \half\,\pi\cot\pars{\pi p \over q} +
2\sum_{k = 1}^{\left\lfloor\,{\pars{q + 1}/2}\,\right\rfloor - 1}
\cos\pars{2\pi kp \over q}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{\pi k \over q}}
$$
$\ds{\gamma}$ is the *Euler-Mascheroni Constant*.

---

The final result becomes:
$$
\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over x^{6} + 1}} =
\color{#f00}{{1 \over 6}\bracks{\pi + \root{3}\ln\pars{2 + \root{3}}}} \approx 0.9038
$$

Comment: Many people do not agree with me, but my personal opinion is that answers like yours, despite being more or less "overkills", give a great learning opportunity to MSE users. So a big (+1) from my side.

Comment: Thanks, @JackD'Aurizio . It's quite grateful to hear that from one of the masters. I got a lot of down-votes because I try to use somehow straightforward evaluations ( like this ===> http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1879648/85343 ).

Comment: Question if you don't mind. $\frac{1}{x^6+1}=\frac{x^6-1}{(x^6-1)(x^6+1)}=..\frac{1-x^6}{1-x^{12}}$, may you please tell me what's the next algebra step?

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Thanks for your remark. In order to bring the integral as close as we can to the Digamma function integral representation, the simplest way is to multiply and divide by $1 - x^{6}$. After that we just need the 'scaling' $x^{6} \mapsto x$. 
$$
\Psi\left(\, z\, \right) + \gamma =
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - t^{z - 1} \over 1 - t}\,\,\,\mathrm{d}t\,,\qquad
\Re\left(\, z\, \right) > 0
$$

Comment: @FelixMarin now I see the substitution $u=x^12$, I think you meant $x^12 \mapsto x$. Anyhow, your comment made it obvious how to proceed and thanks for responding.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Yes. You're right. Sorry. A misprint.

Answer (score 3):

It is easier to solve this integral using partiel fraction decomposition

$\frac{1}{1+x^6} =\frac{1}{3(1+x^2)}+\frac{2-x^2}{3(x^4-x^2+1)}$

and solving the 3 integrals seperatly.

Comment: Actually you can divide the one with 4th grade in denominator further.

Comment: also  some $\pm$ signs are wrong in the quartic

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

note that 
$$
x^6+1=(x^2+1)(x^2-\sqrt{3}+1)(x^2+\sqrt{3}+1)
$$

than use partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 2):

By writing the integrand function as its Taylor series centered at $x=0$ and performing termwise integration we get:
$$ I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x^6}=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{6k+1}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{12k+1}-\frac{1}{12k+7}\right).\tag{1} $$
The last series can now be computed through the discrete Fourier transform (DFT).
Let $\left\{\omega=\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{6}\right),\omega^5,\omega^7,\omega^{11}\right\}$ be the set of the primitive twelth roots of unity and $\chi(n)$ be the arithmetic function that equals $+1$ if $n\equiv\!1\!\!\pmod{12}$, $-1$ if $n\equiv\!7\!\!\pmod{12}$ and zero otherwise.
We have:

$$\chi(n) = \frac{1}{12}\left(-2\omega^5 \omega^n -2i \omega^{3n}-2\omega \omega^{5n}+2\omega^5\omega^{7n}+2i\omega^{9n}+2\omega \omega^{11n}\right)\tag{2}$$
and for every $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,11\}$ the equality:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\omega^{kn}}{n}=-\log(1-\omega^k)\tag{3} $$
holds. By putting everything together,
$$ I = \sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{12k+1}-\frac{1}{12k+7}\right) =\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\chi(n)}{n}= \color{red}{\frac{\pi+\sqrt{3}\log(2+\sqrt{3})}{6}}\tag{4} $$
easily follows from $2+\sqrt{3}=\cot\frac{\pi}{12}$.

---

Another approach is to use the substitution $\frac{1}{1+x^6}=y$ to get:
$$ I = \frac{1}{6}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}y^{-1/6}(1-y)^{-5/6}\,dy \tag{5}$$
then, by setting 
$$ J=\frac{1}{6}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}y^{-1/6}(1-y)^{-5/6}\,dy = \frac{1}{6}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}(1-y)^{-1/6}y^{-5/6}\,dy \tag{6} $$
noticing that:
$$ I+J=\frac{1}{6}\int_{0}^{1}y^{-1/6}(1-y)^{-5/6}\,dy=\frac{\pi}{3}\tag{7}$$
by Euler's beta function and the reflection formulas for the $\Gamma$ function, while $I-J$ provides the logarithmic contribute.

Comment: What a creative answer! Can you please provide an intermediate step or two before expression $(2)$? I am not very well versed in DFT, but I really want to grasp the idea...

Comment: @GeorgSaliba: the central idea is to represent $\chi(n)$ as a linear combination of $\alpha_1^n,\ldots,\alpha_k^n$. Since we are able to compute $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\alpha^n}{n}$, we are also able to compute $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\chi(n)}{n}$, that is the wanted integral. Truth to be told, to use the DFT is perfectly equivalent to apply partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Yes, I understand the big picture, what I'm not getting is how to obtain expression $(2)$. What's the general form?

Comment: @GeorgSaliba: if $\omega=\exp\frac{2\pi i}{k}$, then $$\chi(n)=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}\omega^{jn} $$ is the function that equals $1$ only at the multiples of $k$. By playing a bit with the indices (replacing $n$ in the last sum with $n-\tau$) you get the function that equals one only at $n\equiv\tau\pmod{k}$, then it is just a matter of rearranging terms.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing where MK12 left off, we proceed as follows:

$$\frac{2-x^2}{x^4-x^2+1} = \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{4-2x^2}{x^4-x^2+1} = \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1+x^2 + 3(1-x^2)}{x^4-x^2+1}$$

Split the sub-integral into two parts. For one, make the substitution $u=x+\frac{1}{x}$ and the other $v = x-\frac{1}{x}$

Then the rest should be fairly trivial, provided you are meticulously careful with the limits of integration.